# How can i send a message of how long of a command cooldown is left discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i am making a discord bot. i have added the cooldown using `from discord.ext.commands import CommandOnCooldown`but i don't know how to send a message explaing that you have to wait before you can do the command again. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your error handler

```
if isinstance(error, CommandOnCooldown):
  await ctx.send(f"You are on cooldown now. Please retry after {error.retry_after} seconds.")
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. A vague "add this" is not really helpful, even if the answer is correct.

Comment: I did not need to explain for something simple enough to be understood when it was seen.

Comment: You always have to add at least one sentence of explanation

Comment: Thanks this worked. Explanation aren't always needed like this, since even if you do not know what exactly they mean searching on google may still help you. Thank you